# $1$ big circle formed by $27$ smaller circles

Tags: geometry

I have $27$ small circles of radius $40$ pixels. I want to form $1$ big circle from these. 
How can I find the positions of each?

I also want to have a small gap between each small circle.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not well posed. What do you mean with "forming 1 big circle from these"?  Moreover, it is not clear if the position of the circles is fixed or not.

Comment: In particular, do you want your big circle "filled" or not filled? In the latter case you want to divide the circumference of the circle into 27 equally spaced points, in the former it becomes a bit more tricky.

Comment: Do you mean finding the arrangement such that if you were to compare the area of the enclosing circle of your 40 circles and the area contained in the 40 itself that it will be minimized?

Comment: Well i have 27 circles of radius 40 pixels. I want to create 1 large circle/ring from  these 27 circles. Im wondering if there is a formula to work out the positions each smaller circle needs take...

Comment: The [circles in circles page](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirincir/) of [Erich's Packing Center](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/packing.html) only goes to 20, but is this the kind of question you are asking? Or more like [covering](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/circovcir/) instead of packing? Or something else?

Comment: Hi,  No its not circles inside a circle.  Its making a circle/ring from 27 circles of 40  pixel radius. Im just trying to calculate the position of each of the smaller circles on a X and Y axis to form this large circle/ring

Comment: @MvG, [here](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/) is a site which has the best known packings of equal circles in circle up to $N = 1500$.

Comment: cool but i dont want to pack circles in a circle

Comment: $$\frac{r}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{N})} \left( \cos(\frac{2\pi k}{N}), \sin(\frac{2\pi k}{N}) \right),\quad\quad\text{ where } k = 0,\ldots, N-1$$ for placing $N$ circles of radius $r$ on the circumference of a bigger circle.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to arrange your circle centers like this:

[image: Regular 27-gon]

The points drawn here form a regular 27-gon. They are spaced at regular angles, i.e. the angle $AOB$ (marked yellow) is $\frac{360°}{27}$. The point $C$ is the midpoint between $A$ and $B$. The line $OC$ is perpendicular to $AB$. So $OAC$ is a right triangle. $OA$ is its hypothenuse, and $\frac{180°}{27}$ is its angle at $O$. Call the length of the hypothenuse $r$, since this is also the radious of the circumcircle. Then you get

$$\lvert A,C\rvert = r\sin\frac{180°}{27}$$

If you want your circles to touch one another, then you'd want the distance $\lvert A,C\rvert$ to be equal to the radius of your circles, i.e. 40 pixels. If you want to have “a small gap” between them, then add half that gap to the distance $\lvert A,C\rvert$. In the result, the distance $\lvert A,B\rvert$ between neighbouring circle centers will be twice the radius plus the desired gap. Once you know your ideal $\lvert A,C\rvert$, you can solve the above equation for $r$.

Once you know $r$, you can choose your circle centers by computing angles at regular intervals, and converting from polar coordinates to Cartesian ones.

\begin{align*}
 \varphi_i &= \frac{i}{27}\cdot360° \quad( + \theta ) \\
 x_i &= r\cos\varphi_i \quad( + x_C ) \\
 y_i &= r\sin\varphi_i \quad( + y_C )\\
\end{align*}

The optional addition of $\theta$ to all angles simply rotates the setup as a whole. Similarly, the offsets $x_C$ and $y_C$ can be used to shift the center of the whole setup to an arbitrary location.